# LibGdx getUserData() method -> PC CPU 100%

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

Okay I haven't seen anything like that.

I'm doing game in LibGdx. I've set up, contact listener on my world object so I have 4 methods in my class  ( begin contact, end contact, presolve, postsolve)

```
    @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

            Fixture f1 = contact.getFixtureB();
            float fl =  (Float) f1.getBody().getUserData();             

        // More code goes here

        }
```

If I run my game, the CPU will increase to around 8%. If I run it second time it will go around 20%, third time around 30% and then soon it will be 100% ( I closed all instances of a game ). So even the game is NOT running the CPU will stay at 100%. I can fix this by closing and reopening Eclipse.

I went step by step in my code and if I comment this line

```
float fl =  (Float) f1.getBody().getUserData();
```

everything works okay. Even if I run 10 instances of a game at the same time, my CPU won't go above 30%.

Any ideas?

My computer specs: Intel Pentium QuadCore Q6600 2.4Ghz, 4GB RAM...

Comment: Which version of libgdx are you using? And it's not possible that the processes are stopped, but the CPU is still at 100%. Are you sure that the processes all terminated and are not in a waiting state?

Comment: I'm using libgdx-0.9.9 version. And no I'm not sure if processes are terminated. How can I check that in eclipse? I thought that if you close (x button) the game window, all processes are stopped. In my case even If I explicitly stop ( x button ) window, the CPU is still at 100%. I can solve this problem by closing/opening eclipse again. The other strange part is that I tried also on my second PC (laptop) and the symptomes are the same. (Using the same project )

Comment: In eclipse you can see it, if there's still the red square button (console view) to terminate the process. If this one is still there, it's not terminated (which can happen even if you closed the window).

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, Even i explicitly click the red square button, the CPU is still at 100%.

Comment: Okay I need to buy you a beer. Actually that was it. My game was crashing due to the exception. And I was opening a few instances of the game after a crash for another testing. The console window in Eclipse show the red square button only for last opened instance of the program. And even If I terminated that instance, (red square became gray) the other instances probably were still running hence big CPU usage. Now I explicitly terminated every window and the CPU never went above 5%. Please answer this below so I can accept your answer and others can see that too, if the will have similar prob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not possible for a process to keep running, after you've terminated it.

It might be that you close a window, but the process is still running. In Eclipse you can easily see if a process is still active, or not when you check the red square button in the console view. If this one is still active and can be pressed, the process is still running. Clicking that should kill the process, even if it's stuck in an endless loop for example.

If you run several instances of your program at the same time, the console view will only show one of the instances at a time, but you can switch which one it's supposed to show via the little triangle next to the little monitor icon (Tooltip: "Display selected console"). That way you can check all instances and see if any of them is still running.

Comment: That was it. Thank you :) (+1 ) because you told where I can see other  instances :)